# Create ZIP of hundred thousand files based on date newer than one year on Linux

Tags: linux, zip, compression

I have a /folder with over a half million files created in the last 10 years. I'm restructuring the process so that in the future there are subfolders based on the year.

For now, I need to backup all files modified within the last year. I tried

```
zip -r /backup.zip $(find /folder -type f -mtime -365
```

but get error: Argument list too long.

Is there any alternative to get the files compressed and archived?

Comment: Does this link provide you a solution -> https://haydenjames.io/bash-usr-bin-rm-argument-list-too-long-solution/#:~:text=The%20%E2%80%9Cargument%20list%20too%20long%E2%80%9D%20error%20means%20that%20you',for%20arguments%20in%20a%20command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zip has an option to read the filelist from `stdin`. Below is from the zip man page

> `-@` file lists.  If a file list is specified as `-@` [Not on MacOS],
> zip takes the list of input files from standard input instead of
> from the command line.  For example,
>
> ```
>       zip -@ foo
> ```
>
> will store the files listed one per line on stdin in foo.zip.

This should do what you need

```
find /folder -type f -mtime -365 | zip -@ /backup.zip
```

Note that I've removed the `-r` option because it isn't doing anything - you are explicitly selecting standard files with the find command (`-type f`)

Answer (score 1):

You can also work with the -exec parameter in `find`, like this:
`find /folder -type f -mtime -365 -exec zip -r /backup.zip \;`
(or whatever your command is). For every file, the given command is executed with the file passed as a last parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to switch from passing all the files at once to piping the files one at a time to the zip command.

```
find /folder -type f -mtime -365 | while read FILE;do zip -r /backup.zip $FILE;done
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the files and then execute the zip command on as many files as possible using + as opposed to ;

```
find /folder -type f -mtime -365 -exec zip -r /backup.zip '{}' +
```